# npm install: Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, node-sass

I have a angular application: https://github.com/XBITSwitzerland/ngx-admin/tree/ng2-admin

And now I try to do: `npm install`

But I get this error (The compete Output of the command was way too long, so I just share here the last part):

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\github\ngx-admin\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\github\\ngx-admin\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\github\ngx-admin\node_modules\wintersmith-sassy\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN ngx-toastr@4.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toastr@4.4.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\danyb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-29T18_25_12_699Z-debug.log
```

Does someone have an Idea why this error occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: If you need to install exactly 3.13.1 you will need to downgrade Node.JS to v7 or less

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you run into this issue, read this page: https://www.bramvandenbulcke.be/en/kb/failed-node-sass3131-postinstall-script

The solution in my case:

1) Delete the `package-lock.json` file

2) `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`

3) `npm install node-sass@latest`

**Version specific notes:**

`node-sass@3.13.1` runs only on versions of `Node.js` up to v7 as stated in the [release notes](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1):

Comment: I tried only to delete package-lock.json file and run npm install to whatever the package i want and it worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

I think this is happening because you're missing the node-sass module. Try the following and rerun your build script and see if this resolves your issue:

```
npm install node-sass@latest
```

Also, I see you're using [fsevents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) on a Windows platform, just a warning this module is only supported for Native access to OS X FSEvents

Answer (score 10):

I had error `node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: node scripts/build.js` on npm install after this message

```
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /var/www/my/armat/www/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
```

and spent hours to find solution. I was trying to install it on `laravel 5.2` that uses older versions of node and npm this helped me

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n 6.10.2    // selecting version you need in my case 6.10.2
$ npm install -g npm@3.10.10 // same for npm
```

hope this will help somebody else ^_^

#######UPDATE###########

```
nvm install 6.10.2
nvm use 6.10.2
npm install -g npm@3.10.10
```

Comment: this was the same issue for me. used nvm to downgrade from v12 to v10.

Comment: this was the same issue for me. I was using v10. I downgraded it to v6 and it was working. It is related to the file it tries to download from node-sass, which for v10 was "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/linux-x64-64_binding.node", which does not exist ( the files are named linux-x64-{11,14,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,51}_binding.node, but not 64 (or in your case, 72). However, downgrading from v10 to v6 fixed the problem (downgrading to v8 only changed the 64 to 57, which is still not enough).

Answer (score 2):

only delete

> package-lock.json

file

and do `npm install` again

Comment: Nope this won't work. Gulp sass needs to be installed to eliminate that specific error.

Answer (score 1):

I also received the same error

"npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm **ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`**
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above."

**Solution:**

I increased node-sass and gulp-sass versions to latest in package.json file, then issue got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll further up in the error output and you see something like:

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```

You can fix it on windows with the following steps:

1. delete `node_modules` folder
2. run `npm install --global windows-build-tools`in powershell as admin
3. reinstalling node modules or node-sass with `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

For me, problem was with the Linux directory permissions. Even with sudo and root user I couldn't make it work.

The solution to me was to change project directory owner as follows:

```
sudo chown my_user:my_user -R /path/to/project
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following commands respectively:

```
rm -rf package-lock.json

npm install node-sass@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu

1. Delete the package-lock.json file
2. `sudo npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`
3. `sudo npm install node-sass@latest`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio run following command:

```
npm cache clean --force
 npm config set msvs_version 2019 --global
```

where **2019** is the version of Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **OpenBSD**, that's because you need **g++**. Install it using

```
pkg_add g++
```

But, it gets installed as **ec++**, on **/usr/local/bin**, so you can copy, rename, or **create a symlink** to it using:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/ec++ /usr/local/bin/g++
```

Do the **npm install** again and it should work

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. For different Node versions, different node-saas versions work. My Node version is 10 and I installed node-sass@4.9 successfully. Basically below information helped me. Visiting the site and choosing the correct version of node-saas as per the Node version will help a lot.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely,
there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that
still use it should move onto Dart Sass.

Node 11     4.10+, <5.0     67

Node 10     4.9+, <6.0  64